# Erro ao passar JavaScritp para jQuery onScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como eu consigo converter:

```
window.onscroll = function (){

    var elemento = document.querySelector("div#valores > section.valores > ul");
    elemento.classList.add("animated");
    elemento.classList.add("fadeInUp");
    elemento.classList.add("delay-2s");

}
```

Eu até consegui com o **código** abaixo, mas o efeito ***não*** está acontecendo quando o elemento recebe o `focus`.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("div#comoFunciona > section.comoFunciona > article").addClass("animated fadeInUp delay-2s");
    $("div#valores > section.valores > ul").addClass("animated fadeInUp delay-2s");
});
```

Onde estou errando?

Vale ressaltar que com o **código** **JS** funciona como esperado!

Comment: Meu, mas no seu script não tem escrito nenhuma vez a palavra Focus... Como assim onde estou errando, é meio óbvio não?! Se não tem focus no código como quer que ele funcione? Sua pergunta nem faz sentido

Comment: Geremias acho que você não entendeu o espírito da coisa. quando escrevi focus, no referia ao momento em que o scroll chega na posição em que o elemento está para que o efeito DELE aconteça. Entendeu? Vale AINDA ressaltar que com o código JS funciona como esperado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara pra não vejo vantagem em transformar seu JS em jQuery, até pq com JS vc pode facilmente usa o `Intersection Observer` para "observar" o elemento que quer colocar a classe e só fazer isso quando ele entrar na tela, ou como vc diz, quando estiver em foco. Veja a documentação aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Não vou me alongar em detalhes da API, mas a config que fiz foi para quando o elemento estiver com 50% dele dentro da tela ele adiciona a classe, vc pode controlar isso aqui `const options = { threshold: 0.5 };` os valores vão de 0 a 1, logo 0.5 é 50%. Se vc não quiser usar o tamanho do elemento e usar uma medida fixa, vc pode retirar o `threshold` e usar o `rootMargin`. Se vc quer que o elemento entre 25px na tela antes de aplicar a classe vc pode colocar por exemplo `rootMargin: "-25px 0px",` no lugar do `threshold`.

Outra coisa é que vc não precisa de fazer o `classList` como vc fez, vc pode colocar tudo junto separando por vírgula...

```
.classList.add("animated", "fadeInUp", "delay-2s", 'ativo');
```

O efeito ficaria assim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código.

```js
const sec = document.querySelector('div');
const options = {
    threshold: 0.5
};
const obs = new IntersectionObserver(function(entradas, obs) {
    entradas.forEach(entra => {
        if (!entra.isIntersecting) {
            return;
        }
        entra.target.classList.add("animated", "fadeInUp", "delay-2s", 'ativo');
        obs.unobserve(entra.target);
    });
}, options);

obs.observe(sec);
```

```css
body {
    margin-top: 120vh;
}

div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.ativo {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```